# How to configure NGINX with php-fpm on mac

Tags: php, macos, nginx, configuration

Been facing this issue now for quite a long time. New on nginx so need help
Basically Im trying to configure nginx settings to use my PHP projects. Before I was using Apache (MAMP) to run all my php proj. Now im shifting to nginx. I have configured all possible settings needed in nginx.conf file (have a look below). But still im facing rather the same issue and im not able to correctly address it for some reason.

```
...nginx default settings
nginx.conf
server{
    listen 80;

    error_log /usr/local/etc/nginx/log/freespinswizard-error.log;
    access_log /usr/local/etc/nginx/log/freespinswizard-access.log;
    access_log off;

    #location / {
        root   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/freespinswizard/;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    #}

    #root /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/freespinswizard/;
    #index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name www.freespinswizard.com freespinswizard.com;

    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|ico|xml|otf)$ {
        access_log        off;
        log_not_found     off;
        expires           30d;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/freespinswizard.sock;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
        #fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        #fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
        #fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        #fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
        include fastcgi_params;
        add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
    }

    rewrite ^/offers/([^/\.]*)/?$ /page-handler.php?story-page-slug=$1 break;
    rewrite ^/ab/([^/\.]*)/?$ /page-handler.php?group-key-name=$1 break;

    if ($request_uri !~ "(^/scripts/)"){
        rewrite ^/.*.php.* /page-handler.php break;
    }

    if ($request_uri !~ "(^/.*\..*)"){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /page-handler.php break;
    }
}
......nginx default settings continued
```

Error im facing in log file regarding the website im trying to host

```
2020/11/04 20:14:49 [error] 21300#0: *1 kevent() reported that connect() failed (61: 
Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 
www.freespinswizard.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", 
host: "freespinswizard.com"
```

I have no clue what is wrong in my configurations. Please any kind of help would be appreciated, thnx in advance.

Comment: How is FPM configured?  Is it IP based or socket based?  Is it using port 9000?

Comment: how to check that? Im sorry im really new to all this..

Comment: You should have php-fpm.conf or fpm.d/*.conf somewhere.  You are looking for the `listen = ` declaration.

Comment: i found it in /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf.default and i checked that listen = 127.0.0.1:9000...im supposing its IP based and using port 9000...

Comment: So by default I believe fpm does something like `include=/etc/php/fpm-php7.4/fpm.d/*.conf`, it is possible that the .default file just needs to be renamed to .conf but I can't be sure without looking at your config.  Be sure to restart FPM after making that change.

Comment: actually there is a little catch i forgot to mention...im using php5 for my php project but my default php is php7 and im guessing my fpm is also for php7...could that be causing issue?

Comment: Probably not this particular issue, it looks like nginx is not able to open a connection to FPM regardless of its version.  You may have to make some small code changes when upgrading to 7 from 5, but they should be pretty minor.